# Why doesn't English (US) have speech recognition settings in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language-pack, speech-recognition

I have multiple windows 10 machines where above the keyboard options, I can click "Download text-to-speech" or something similar so I can use speech recognition, however I do no longer get the option.

[No option to download text-to-speech or speech recognition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHXlK.png)

My country is set to United States.

My display language is set to English (US), but when I try to activate speech recognition, windows says I need to change my display language to English (US).

How can I make windows 10 let me download speech recognition packs?

Comment: If you create a new user does the option exist?  This user will be a test, and based on your response, will indicate what language new users are set to use by default.  Having your display language set to English US isn't necessarily enough.

Comment: Have you also set the Regional format to English (United States)? Or maybe can you remove and reinstall the language English (US) to check the speech? And you can also update the windows to the latest version for more speech configuration.